# Python Nested Lists: Table Printer function

Tags: python, nested-lists

The goal of this program was to take in a nested list called tableData and write a function that displays organized columns that are right-justified. The function works for the code but I would like to get some feedback or to know if I can be done more efficiently for problems in the future. 
  apples Alice  dogs 
  oranges   Bob  cats 
 cherries Carol moose 
   banana David goose

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
['Alice','Bob','Carol', 'David'], 
['dogs', 'cats','moose','goose']]

def printTable():
    colWidths = [0]* len(tableData)
    one = []
    two = []
    three = []


    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        colWidths[i] = tableData[i]
        place = tableData[i]
        for x in range(len(tableData[i])):
            spot = colWidths
            if len(one) < len(place):
                one.append(colWidths[i][x])
            elif len(two) < len(place):
                two.append(colWidths[i][x])
            elif len(three) < len(place):
                three.append(colWidths[i][x])

    for i in range(len(one)):
        print((one[i]+'  ' +two[i]+ '  ' +three[i]).center(20,))


printTable()
```

Comment: You may want to try over at CodeReview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is a great spot for getting tips on improving working code.

Comment: In case you're looking for a ready-made solution, I've had success using the `tabulate` module (https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate). It's included in Anaconda, and available in the Debian repositories if you don't want to use pip.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a built in method called zip which allows us to combine iterables into a single variable. If you were to combine this with pythons `unpacking` ability, the code becomes quite condensed.

```
tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
['Alice','Bob','Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats','moose','goose']]

things = list(zip(*tableData))
for tuple in things:
    print('{} {} {}'.format(*tuple).rjust(20))
```

What we did here was to take the `tabledata` and split it using the unpacker `*`, then we zip it, so we get a tuple containing one of each value from the separated lists.

We then iterate through `things` and split each tuple, again using unpacking. Finally, we can use `rjust()` to get that right justify

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying loop, you can try below -

```
import pandas as pd

tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
['Alice','Bob','Carol', 'David'], 
['dogs', 'cats','moose','goose']]

df = pd.DataFrame(tableData)

df_transpose = df.transpose()


df_transpose['final'] = df_transpose.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().values.tolist()), axis=1)

with pd.option_context('display.colheader_justify','right'):
    print(df_transpose['final'].to_string(index=False,header=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer not takes in all length of the strings in the list values.
Also the length of the longest string should be given as width value for rjust.

### AnswerCode:

```
tableData=[["apples","oranges","cherries","banana"],
           ["Alice","Bob","Carol","David"],
           ["dogs","cat","moose","goose"]]
colWidth=[0]*len(tableData)     
def printtable(data):
    colWidths = [0] * len(tableData)
    
    for y in range(len(tableData)): #finding the length of strings in each sublist
        for x in tableData[y]:
            if colWidths[y] < len(x):
                colWidths[y] = len(x)
    width=max(colWidths) # finding the length of the longest in the list
    for j in range(len(data[0])):     
        for i in range(len(data)):
            print(data[i][j].rjust(int(width)), end = " ")
        print("\n")
printtable(tableData)
```

Hope this helps.